# Update multiple MySQL tables with HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have a database with four tables. I join them, display all fields in an HTML form and want users to be able to update the fields. There are a lot of fields, and these do change sometimes, so I don't want to hardcode the column names. What I do is selecting all tables and all columns and then loop through each element to create the table. This works great - the form is populated with the results of the sql query. But I then need to be able to update the fields, and for that I need the `$_POST` to take the form of `Table_Name.Column_Name` - I want to loop through all posts again. 
What I have tried to do was to set the `name` property of my input field to `$tablename . chr(46) . $fieldname` in my PHP file, but this is replaced to `$tablename_$fieldname` upon posting (period is replaced by underscore). As I have said I would like to avoid hardcoding the table names into my update PHP file. Is there any way to avoid this - I can't seem to figure out a way to pass the table names to the PHP file. Unfortunately, some columns have underscores in their name, so I cannot easily use a string replacement function.

Comment: Please, show us some code and structurize your question. We want questions, that could be quickly understood.

Comment: sorry about that. I have realised that it doesn't work either way because I cannot update multiple tables at once, so I guess the question is moot.. many thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using separate the name into identifiers for table and column? Something like

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="tablename" value="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="columnanme" value="...">
    <input type="text name="updatevalue" value="...">
    ...
</form>
```

An alternative if you want use javascript is to create and send a JSON object.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I found a solution - not very elegant but I set the HTML name to table^column and then string replace "^" to "."